# Replacing one line of code with another in vim?

Tags: search, vim, replace, line

I have one line of code that I need to replace in Vim. I need to replace one line of code `errors += 1;` to `errors++;` just to simplify it.

When I do `:%s/errors += 1;/errors++;/a` I get `E488:Trailing Characters`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I my vim 7.2 it works fine, however you can try this: :%s/errors\ +=\ 1;/errors++;/gc<CR>

Comment: I did try the space delimiters but it seems to be the different flags at the end that did it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `/a` at the end as a *flag*: `a` isn't a substitute flag. Without the `a` this should work for you.

Use `c` if you want to manually confirm each replacement.

Use `g` if you want to replace all occurrences on a line.

Comment: Thank you!! For some reason I had thought the /a meant "all" but the normal search/replace function without the flag did work perfectly! Thanks!